# how to change the value of cells with past date

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

i am trying to select only past dates in a range. So in the column B, I need that all the cells with a date previous from today say "date already gone". I am a beginner and have tried this code but its not working.

```
Sub FilterDateBeforeToday()

Set rrg = "dd/mm/yyyy"

rrg = Range("b1:b2000")
If rrg = Now - 1 Then

ActiveCell.Value = "data already gone"

End If
End Sub
```

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

As long as all of B1:B2000 are dates. You will need to loop through each cell and check if it is a previous date.

```
for i = 1 to 2000
    if range("B" & i).value < now - 1 then range("B" & i).value = "Data already gone"
next
```

If you just put it as `activecell.value` then what ever cell you have active before the macro ran would change.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each cell in the range and then check whether the date has passed.

```
Public Sub RemovePastDates()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B2000")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <= Now - 1 Then
        cell.Value = "Date has passed"
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Note that I've explicitly referenced the workbook and worksheet to ensure that the correct worksheet is amended.

Comment: just mind the subtile difference between `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: the macro runs, but not as i expected. it doesnt select all the date from the past

Comment: I understood the problem. The dates that i have on my sheet are the result of a formula, then it doesnt work. If i just write the dates without any formulas, it works. Do you know how to adjust your code in order to accept formula results as well?

Comment: does the formula really result in a Date ... or rather in a Text which looks like a date?

Answer (score 0):

`Set rrg` requires a Range object, not a string as in <strike>`Set rrg = "dd/mm/yyyy"`</strike>

`rrg = Range("b1:b2000")` would be correct if proceeded with `Set` (I am using the [] notation which is simpler for single cell assignments like e.g. in `Set rrg = [A1]` ...)

`If rrg = Now - 1 Then` ... `rrg` is a range ... you need to repeat the `If` for each cell in that range (e.g. by use of a `For Each` ... see example)

`ActiveCell.Value = "data already gone"` ... regardless of your loop ... `ActiveCell` always refers to the cell of current cursor position

```
Sub FilterDateBeforeToday()
Dim MyRange As Range, MyCell As Range

    Set MyRange = Range([B1], [B1000])

    For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells

        ' test if it contains a date ...
        ' on the 2nd pass we may have a string there already
        If VarType(MyCell) = vbDate Then

            ' use Int() to compare against today 00:00 hrs
            If MyCell < Int(Now()) Then
                MyCell = "Date passed"
            End If

        End If

    Next MyCell

End Sub
```

`Now()` returns a date plus time ... the start of the day is `Now()` with the decimal part removed (`Int()`) ... so everything which is smaller than the start of today is passed ... this is more precise than `< Now()-1` which means smaller than now minus 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Just use autofilter, no need for loops:

```
Sub FilterDateBeforeToday()

With Range("B1:B2000")
    .AutoFilter 1, "<" & CLng(Date) '// Filter any dates before today
    .SpecialCells(12).Value = "Date already gone" '// Replace visible cells with text.
End With

ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False '// Remove filter.

End Sub
```

Comment: it does not work properly, does not select all the dates before today

Comment: Then your dates aren't actually formatted as dates.